# What's the usage difference between element_validate and validate hook?

Tags: hooks, forms

From what i've learned today, there are two ways one can go about validating input.

One is the #element_validate field which is passed along the form hook, and the other is the validate hook.

Why use the validate hook if input can be validated with the #element_validate field? Is it a necessity to implement the validate hook in this case?

Or is it a method that should be implemented for complex validation while all simple validation(is number, is date, is url) can be done via the #element_validate option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Haider Ali with ***#element_validate***, we can add our own custom validation functions to a **field** or we can pass the validation functions provided by Drupal, e.g., **element_validate_integer_positive()**, **element_validate_number()**, etc.

This #element_validate works only on the field we added it to.

When we want to add custom validation to multiple fields, we add it in form **validate hook**, so that we do not need to add separate function to each field and call multiple validate functions.

Comment: Yeah further reading into the API just told me the same thing, thank you however. :) 

However, the validate hook stops execution after first error is thrown, it doesn't seem possible to make a list of errors out of it. Which might be possible from the #element_validate field

Comment: What kind of errors?